# I have problems with this sub-query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named Teams which has these columns: TeamName, TeamID, etc
and a table Matches which has: Team1_id, Team2_id, Team1_Goals, Team2_Goals, etc

I want a table like this: TeamName1 Team1_Goals TeamName2 Team2_Goals

I tried something like:

```
select Teams.TeamName, Matches.Team1_Goals
    , (select Teams.TeamName where Teams.TeamID = Matches.Team2_ID) as TeamName2
    , Matches.Team2_Goals
from Matches
inner join Teams on Teams.TeamID = Matches.Team1_ID
inner join Teams as Teams2 on Teams2.TeamID = Matches.Team2_ID
```

but it doesn't return what I want. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Is your question just about how to format the table to what you want? Also what is your code returning?

Comment: @WesPalmer well yes.  My code returns TeamName1 Team1_Goals as it should, but TeamName2 is always null and Team2_Goals always 0.

Comment: `(select Teams.TeamName ` from where?. Please provide a sample data and the expected results.

Comment: You want a table? Or a resultset? As Sami said, we need to see some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subquery isn't needed. Just pull a `TeamName` from each of the `Team` table joins.

Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.TeamName     AS team1_name
     , m.Team1_Goals   AS team1_goals

     , t2.TeamName     AS team2_name
     , m.Team2_Goals   AS team2_goals 

  FROM Matches m

  JOIN Teams t1
    ON t1.TeamID = m.Team1_ID

  JOIN Teams t2
    ON t2.TeamID = m.Team2_ID

 ORDER
    BY ...
```